# Pig Conditional Statements

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I think I already know the answer to this, but I just wanted to check here before I give up and do something ugly.

I have a query that needs to count total clicks, and also total distinct users.  Total clicks would just be this code without the distinct:

```
report              = FOREACH report GENERATE user, genre, title;
report              = DISTINCT report;
report              = GROUP report BY (genre, title);
```

My question is essentially: is there any way to write a conditional statement that would skip the DISTINCT step in this process?  Pseudo:

```
report              = FOREACH report GENERATE user, genre, title;
if $report_type == 'users':
    report              = DISTINCT report;
end if
report              = GROUP report BY (genre, title);
```

I'd rather not have two separate files, and up to this point the only solutions I can find involve using a Python, etc. wrapper to dynamically deal with it.  I'd rather keep everything in a simple .pig file, but can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be you can try something like this. Can you check with your input?

**input:**

```
user1,action,aa
user2,comedy,cc
user3,drama,dd
user1,action,aa
user1,action,aa
user2,comedy,cc
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS (user, genre, title);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE user, genre, title;
C = GROUP B BY (genre, title);
D = FOREACH C {
                noDistValue = FOREACH B GENERATE user,genre,title;
                distValue =  DISTINCT B;
                GENERATE $0 AS grp,noDistValue,distValue;
              }
E = FOREACH D GENERATE grp,(('$report_type' == 'users')?distValue:noDistValue) AS mybag;
DUMP E;
```

**Output1:**
**>>pig -x local -param "report_type=users" test.pig**

```
((action,aa),{(user1,action,aa)})
((comedy,cc),{(user2,comedy,cc)})
((drama,dd),{(user3,drama,dd)})
```

**Output2:**
**>>pig -x local -param "report_type=nonusers" test.pig**

```
((action,aa),{(user1,action,aa),(user1,action,aa),(user1,action,aa)})
((comedy,cc),{(user2,comedy,cc),(user2,comedy,cc)})
((drama,dd),{(user3,drama,dd)})
```

In case if you want to calculate the Count then project the relation E and also you can modify the above script according to your need.

Comment: This is great and looks better than what I came up with.

I did a kind of hackish thing using parameters and a conditional statement to create a unique id for every record and group on that.  So when I need distinct users it just groups on user_id, but if I need views it groups on a concatenation of date, time, and user_id, which is more or less unique (unique enough for our case).  

    case when '$rollup_type' == 'visits' then CONCAT(CONCAT(dt,tm), user_id) when '$rollup_type' == 'users' then user_id end as user_id.

I look forward to implementing your solution though. Thanks for the input!